# Replacement of 'TabActivity' in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I used TabActivity for tabs in my application. Now TabActivity is deprecated. So I googled and found that 'Fragment' is the replacement for the TabActivity to create a tabs. Can someone guide me to choose the right thing(Fragment or any other) to create a tabs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ActionBarSherlock + Fragments....For details check out...http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html and download the ABS from here..http://actionbarsherlock.com/ .....Tons of tutorials available like this one...[Android Tab Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460291/android-tab-action-bar)

Answer (score 1):

Fragment is the best way to create a tab. If you want a sample you can create a new project in eclipse and choose the navigation type "swipe + tabs", it will create a simple application with three tabs. There are a lot of comments explaining the code and it's very easy to understand.